# Adding BB10 , WP8 to MFP 7.1 cordova project

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, blackberry-10, mobilefirst-cli

I'm developing a new MFP (MobileFirst Platform) Application based on Cordova CLI provided IBM throughout this Tuto [Integrating IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation SDK in Cordova applications](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/) But apparently It doesn't support adding blackberry10 and windowsPhone8 platforms.

Is there a way to add those platforms in an MFP Cordova based projects? so I can built artifacts ( .wlapp ) and have the same behavior for android and ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked this same question in the comments of the tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/updated-using-cli-to-create-build-and-manage-mobilefirst-project-artifacts/#comment-33161

The answer is the same:

> MFP Cordova-baed applications do not support the BlackBerry 10 and Windows Phone 8 platforms.

Comment: is it possible to create an MFP cordova CLI based project , add iOS and Android platform. Then add the blackberry10 and WP8 platforms in the backend MFP project ? So I can build iOS and Android with cordova , but once it comes to BB10 and WP8 I build them with only MFP.

Comment: Your server can serve both MFP Cordova and regular Hybrid apps. You could have 2 projects - one for the Cordova apps and one for the BB/WP8 apps, those 2 projects will be served by the same server.